# How to add ground shadows by Entities created programmatically in RealityKit?

Tags: entity, augmented-reality, arkit, shadow, realitykit

I am trying to create two types of Entities in my project. Both of them, I create them programmatically by generating a MeshResource and a Material.

The first one (named Placement Indicator) has a mesh of Plane and an UnlitMaterial, and I attach a texture on top.
[image]

The second one (name Point Charge) has a mesh of Sphere and a SimpleMaterial.
[image]

Everything works great, except that when these entities appear on the surface of my table, there are no shadows on the table.

How can I make the entities I created to create ground shadows on my table surface?

Answer (score 1):

You can try add lighting in you sceneUnderstanding options.
It simulates light right above your entity to generate shadows

```
ArView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.receivesLighting)
```